# how to change file timestamp in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

In linux, you can use touch to change the timestamp of a file. However, HDFS touchz does not change the file timestamp when the file already exists. Is an easy way to change HDFS timestamp without deleting the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileSystem#setTimes](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#setTimes%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20long,%20long%29) method.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.